# How to join arrays like JavaScript's destructuring?

Tags: functional-programming, rust, concatenation

I want to make a function that receives a `Vec` and a position to change a number.

In JavaScript, this is really simple:

```
function replaceNumber(line, position, number) {
  return [
    ...line.slice(0, position),
    number,
    ...line.slice(position+1, line.length)
  ]
}
```

How can I make a similar function in Rust?

I tried this:

```
fn replace_number(line: Vec<i32>, point: i32, number: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    return [
        &line[0..point as usize],
        &[number],
        &line[point as usize+1, point.len()]
    ].concat();
}
```

The result is an array of arrays. How can I make a destructuring like the JavaScript example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to make a function that receives a Vec and a position to change a number.

Rust has indexing syntax, just like JavaScript, so there's really no need for the destructuring.

```
fn replace_number(mut line: Vec<i32>, point: usize, number: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    line[point] = number;
    line
}
```

or, more idiomatically:

```
fn replace_number(line: &mut Vec<i32>, point: usize, number: i32) {
    line[point] = number
}
```

Even more idiomatically would be to not have this function, probably, and just write it inline...

> I want to know about immutably adding

With your original code, there's **zero** concern about anything "bad" happening because of mutability:

```
fn replace_number(line: Vec<i32>, point: i32, number: i32) -> Vec<i32>
```

This function takes ownership of the `Vec`, so the concept of immutability is rather moot here — the caller no longer has the `Vec` to care if it's mutated or not!

If you wanted to share data, you'd use a reference (a *slice*, specifically) like `&[i32]`. This is inherently immutable — you can't change it if you wanted to. You'd have to clone all the children and make the vector mutable:

```
fn replace_number(line: &[i32], point: usize, number: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut line = line.to_owned();
    line[point] = number;
    line
}
```

If you *really* wanted something like the JS syntax, you can use [`concat`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceConcatExt.html#tymethod.concat):

```
fn replace_number(line: &[i32], point: usize, number: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    [&line[..point], &[number], &line[point + 1..]].concat()
}
```

See also:

- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec) or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: I want to know about immutability adding. I will change the function name. Is a good practice uses mutable variables in rust? I think that "is possible, but isnt good to use". I'm wrong?

Comment: @RenatoCassino that's not an easy question to answer. What are your reasons for avoiding mutability in JS? Do you know *why* mutability causes problems? Rust solves many (but not all) of those problems in different ways.